# WPF Unable to set Selected Item of a Combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a non-bound Combobox and I want to set its value at run time. I tried a lot but cannot achieve it. Here's the code :

```
<ComboBox  Background="#FFB7B39D" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,26,136,0" 
Name="cboWellDiameter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">

     <ComboBoxItem Content="meter" IsSelected="True" />
         <ComboBoxItem Content="centimeter" />
</ComboBox>
```

In code, I am trying with :

```
//VALUE of  sp.wellborediameterField_unit is centimeter
// Gives -1
int index = cboWellDiameter.Items.IndexOf(sp.wellborediameterField_unit);

Console.WriteLine("Index of well bore dia unit = " + index.ToString());  
cboWellDiameter.SelectedIndex = index;

// cboWellDiameter.SelectedItem = sp.wellborediameterField_unit;
// cboWellDiameter.SelectedValue = sp.wellborediameterField_unit;
```

SelectedItem & selectedValue has no impact. Why its not even able to find in Items ? How do I set it ?

Please help me, have several such non-bound and binded combos to set programmatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your items are ComboBoxItems, not strings.  So you have two options: one, use strings as the combo-box items (this allows you to set SelectedItem / SelectedValue = "meter" or "centimeter"):

```
<ComboBox xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
     <clr:String>meter</clr:String>
     <clr:String>centimeter</clr:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**or** two, set the `SelectedItem` by searching for the appropriate `ComboBoxItem`:

```
cboWellDiameter.SelectedItem = cboWellDiameter.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>()
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Content as string == cosp.wellborediameterField_unit);
```

Comment: I don't see any method FirstOrDefault in Items ? Well OfType<> is not not allowed.

Comment: @Tvd oh right, I was using Linq extensions for convenience ... add `using System.Linq;` to be able to use `FirstOrDefault` and `OfType` ...